How to access JWT token from a returned object from third party intergration using nextauth.js
When we try to access the returned object after third party authentication on nextauth.js, I'm unable to access the other keys which are not defined in the user interface of nextauth. id, email, name and image are only accessible fields. How do I extract other fields like JWT Token?
Want to access jwt token access
